# Why is 'java.net.SocketException: jks not found'?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I am passing the following VM arguments to a WS client application that runs on Websphere 5.1.1 JRE, one on  Windows XP and one on Linux but get different behaviors.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=./key.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=abc 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=./key.jks 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trust=abc 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=abc 
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.ibm.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS 
-DtraceSettingsFile=trace.log
```

On Windows all work fine, but on Linux I am getting an exception right where the WS client is supposed to open a connection:

```
java.net.SocketException: jks not found
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.HTTP11Sender$5.run(HTTP11Sender.java:1789)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.HTTP11Sender$SocketPoolFactory.obtainSocket(HTTP11Sender.java:1781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.HTTP11Sender.invoke(HTTP11Sender.java:185)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:212)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.WebServicesEngine.invoke(WebServicesEngine.java:255)
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: I know this may seem silly, but are they both the same jres?  Meaning both sun or both ibm.

Comment: yes, both are 'Classic VM (build 1.4.2, J2RE 1.4.2 IBM ...'

Answer (score 1):

That hard-coded string `com.ibm.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol` may be the cause of your problem if your Linux environment doesn't have the package installed. You might need to find a suitable entry for whatever libraries you do have deployed, or deploy the IBM lib.

---

Update: I found this [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/security/142/secguides/JSSEFIPSDocs/JSSESecurityPolicy.html) with reference to IBM VM versions which might help:

> If you wish to use the HTTPS protocol
>   handler, you must set the property
>   java.protocol.handler.pkgs. In 1.3.x,
>   the https protocol handler is:
>   com.ibm.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol
>   and in 1.4.x, the https protocol
>   handler is:
>   com.ibm.net.ssl.www.protocol. For
>   example to set the HTTPS handler for
>   1.4.x:

Comment: Right on. I've appended the ../jre/lib/ext directory to the ext.dirs list, and now works on Linux too. It seems that the WS client 'likes' ibmjsseprovider2.jar better then ibmjsseprovider.jar
Thanks. Appreciate